# Multisite multidomain

Tags: multisite, customization

I have a wordpress multisite. I'm using a single domain, but **I want to use multiples domains. I want to allow the user choose a domain for his subdomain.**

I was searching, but i don't found nothing about this... only a domain mapping plugin and is for singles sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the **Networks for WordPress** plugin: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/networks-for-wordpress/

It will create a sub-network for each of your domains. So basically you'd have a network of networks of sites. Each sub-network will be using the same install of WordPress, but will be managed separately with it's own sites under it. Like so:

mainsite.com

- site2.com

  - blog1.site2.com
  - blog2.site2.com
- site3.com

  - blog1.site3.com
  - blog2.site3.com

(mainsite.com could also have it's own blogs under it)

Comment: I talk of bz6.org, a opened wordpress mu network. I would can have a open network with this plugin or it is only for multiples personal blogs? 

In my network, the users can create his blog free with a subdomain, I want to do this, but multiples domains for create blogs. I would can do it?

Comment: @LuisGarcía Yes, any domain you add to the network will become a sub-network and blogs can be created under it. Subdomains are supported.